# for loop isn't working to toggle on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops

I'm having trouble getting this for loop to work again, I had it working the other day but I tweaked it to where I can't get it back.

Please help and if you have a solution for this, I would also like to loop through the submenus while looping through the arrows to open submenus.

```js
// index Item 1 //

const indexitem1arrow = document.querySelector('.indexitem1indexarrow');
const indexitem1submenu = document.querySelector('.indexitem1submenu');

const indexItem1Arrows = [
  indexitem2arrow = document.querySelector('.indexitem2indexarrow'),
  indexitem3arrow = document.querySelector('.indexitem3indexarrow'),
  indexitem4arrow = document.querySelector('.indexitem4indexarrow'),
];
const indexItem1ArrowsArrowLoop = () => {
  for (i = 0; i < indexItem1Arrows.length; i++);
  if (indexItem1Arrows[i].classList.contains('rotatearrow')) {
    indexItem1Arrows[i].classList.remove('rotatearrow')
  }
};

const indexItem1Submenus = [
  indexitem2submenu = document.querySelector('.indexitem2submenu'),
  indexitem3submenu = document.querySelector('.indexitem3submenu'),
  indexitem4submenu = document.querySelector('.indexitem4submenu'),
];
const openIndexItem1Submenus = [
  openIndexItem1 =
  () => {
    indexitem1submenu.classList.toggle('hidden');
    indexitem1arrow.classList.toggle('rotatearrow');
  },
  openIndexItem2 =
  () => {
    indexitem2submenu.classList.toggle('hidden');
    indexitem2arrow.classList.toggle('rotatearrow');
  },
  openIndexItem3 =
  () => {
    indexitem3submenu.classList.toggle('hidden');
    indexitem3arrow.classList.toggle('rotatearrow');
  },
  openIndexItem4 =
  () => {
    indexitem4submenu.classList.toggle('hidden');
    indexitem4arrow.classList.toggle('rotatearrow');
  }
];
const indexItem1SubmenusLoop = () => {
  for (i = 0; i < indexItem1Submenus.length; i++);
  if (!indexItem1Submenus[i].classList.contains('hidden')) {
    indexItem1Submenus[i].classList.add('hidden')
  }
};

indexitem1arrow.addEventListener('click', openIndexItem1);
indexitem1arrow.addEventListener('click', indexItem1ArrowsArrowLoop);
indexitem1arrow.addEventListener('click', indexItem1SubmenusLoop);
indexitem2arrow.addEventListener('click', openIndexItem2);
indexitem3arrow.addEventListener('click', openIndexItem3);
indexitem4arrow.addEventListener('click', openIndexItem4);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
.index-list {
  position: static;
  width: calc(100% - 50%);
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: left;
  border: 3px solid #444;
  margin: 0px 105px 100px 100px;
  box-shadow: #333;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: poppins;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.index-list li {
  list-style: none;
}

.index-list li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.index-list li i {
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.index-list .index-itself .index-sub-menu li a {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.index-list .index-itself .index-sub-menu-sub-menu li a {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.index-list li i:hover {
  font-size: 22px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.rotatearrow {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>webpage</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <html lang="en" dir="ltr" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <link rel='stylesheet' href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="index-list">
    <ul class="index-itself">
      <li class="indexitem1 indexitem"><a href="#"><strong>indexitem1</strong></a><i class="fas fa-angle-down indexitem1indexarrow arrow"></i>
        <ul class="indexitem1submenu index-sub-menu hidden">
          <li class="indexitem2 indexitem"><a href="#">indexitem2</a><i class="fas fa-angle-down indexitem2indexarrow arrow"></i>
            <ul class="indexitem2submenu index-sub-menu-sub-menu hidden">
              <li><a href="#">lorem uipson</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">lorem upsim</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="indexitem3index indexitem"><a href="#">indexitem3</a><i class="fas fa-angle-down indexitem3indexarrow arrow"></i>
            <ul class="indexitem3submenu index-sub-menu-sub-menu hidden">
              <li><a href="#">egea</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">lorem upsin</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="indexitem4-index indexitem"><a href="#">indexitem4</a><i class="fas fa-angle-down indexitem4indexarrow arrow"></i>
            <ul class="indexitem4submenu index-sub-menu-sub-menu hidden">
              <li><a href="#">lorem ipson</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">loreme ipson</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

I've tried using querySelectorAll to target the index items.
I had this working the other day until I tried switching everything to querySelectorAll.

Comment: indexItem1ArrowsArrowLoop the for loop. You are ending it with ; which means null statement , do nothing is that the purpose?

Comment: Aside: you should get in the habit of properly declaring your loop variables.

Comment: isn't `indexitem3index` a typo?

Comment: how would i properly declare my loop variables?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @JohnVining: `for (let i = 0...` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this approach:

```
 const arrows = document.querySelectorAll('.arrow');

    arrows.forEach(arrow => {
      arrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const submenu = arrow.parentElement.querySelector('.index-sub-menu');
        if(submenu) submenu.classList.toggle('hidden');
      })
    })
```

Here i'm querySelecting all of the arrows and adding a click listener to every single one that on click will select the submenu and toggle the hidden class. Add a .js-submenu to the sub-menu elements and replace the '.index-sub-menu' (in the JS only) class in the querySelector to seperate the CSS classes from the JS logic.

You could also do this by adding 1 event listener to the document like so:

```
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if(!event.target.classList.contains('arrow')) return;
  
  const submenu = event.target.parentElement.querySelector('.index-sub-menu')
    if(submenu) submenu.classList.toggle('hidden');
})
```

It listens for a click event. Checks if the target of the event has the class '.arrow' and repeats the same logic as the previous example. I hope this was helpful

Comment: I understand but why are you using the ! operator in the if statement? on the second block shouldn't it be if(event.target.classList.contains('arrow')) ?

Comment: Sorry. When any click event occurs it gives us the event.target which is the element that was clicked. The reason for the if statement is to check if the event.target does NOT have the .arrow class. If it doesn't, then that means it's another element and we don't have to do anything so we return from the function.